# How to translate this sentence to logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

All college students in this class know each other.

How can I translate this sentence with quantifiers?

CS: for college students

Class: for  in class

Knows(x,y) for knows

Comment: To start you off, think what the initial statement is ("All"), hence it seems reasonable to being with the universal quantifier $\forall x,y \in \text{CS} . . . $ Try going from there.

Comment: For all $x$ and $y$ that are element of $CS$, if C(x) is true and C(y) is true then Knows(x,y) = true.